# Win8 Metro - Reset roaming and local settings?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm trying to find a quick solution to cleanup/reset the roaming settings. I'm having to do this manually within code and have to have the development environment running.

Is there a reset switch?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The data is stored locally at `%localappdata%\Packages\<packageID>`.  You can delete it from the client directly from there.  See [Accessing app data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx) for more info.

Comment: *Roaming* appdata should be in %appdata%\Packages\<packageID>

Answer (score 2):

Better late to the party then never, but:

You can do this by right clicking on your app in the solution explorer, selecting the Properties, navigate to the Debug tab, and click "Uninstall and then re-install my package."

This should at least nuke stuff from the LocalSettings, but I don't think it affects the Roaming stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the `[ApplicationData.current.clearAsync()][1]` function is for--it'll flush all of it.

Comment: Thanks. Specifically, running `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.clearAsync()` in the JavaScript Console will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is any way inside of Visual Studio to do this, but there is a way to detect the debug mode and to also access the files directly from windows explorer. Therefore, the options you have are:

- Leave your code in that does resets the data store, but detect debug mode by checking [Debug.debuggerEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh969516%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) property on launch of your application. If you want to clear everything I would recommend checking up on the `clearAsync` function which will wipe out your entire local data store for the application. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.clearasync.aspx) for more information.
- The option @JPAlioto suggested of manually clearing the folder. You could do this as a build step pretty easily.

Comment: @RadiantHex I've updated my answer with some new information which I think may help you. Just a heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to clear 'someSetting' saved in localSettings. You can use:

var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings;
localSettings.values.remove("someSetting");

Same goes for roamingSettings I guess.